# Xamarin App - Logging / Monitoring Solution

Tags: c#, android, logging, xamarin, monitoring

I have a Xamarin.Forms App. I'm looking for a logging, monitoring and crash report solution. The key is that my app can run offline and the logging / crash reports must be send to the server automatically when the app is online again.

Are there any existing solutions? I looked at https://hockeyapp.net/ but i'm not sure if it supports offline apps.

Answer (score 0):

HockeyApp will save the crashes, and upload them when there is an available connection.

Microsoft is also in the space with Application Insights / Mobile Center (currently in preview), which I have used and found useful for logging events and crashes. Although their own docs show that they basically wrap the HockeyApp service (src https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-center/) for the crash reporting.